# How to get data out of request using jQuery and Flask

Tags: jquery, python, flask

For whatever reason, I'm having the hardest time getting the data I care about out of my request object in Flask. I'm trying to give the user a way to save their system of differential equations as different types of files that are generated server-side when the GET request is sent, I just need to know what file type they want. This is the code to send the request:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/',
            data: selected_index,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                downString = response.downloadString;
            }
        });
```

and this is the code to choose which file to generate then send it back in a dictionary, so that *downString* is set to that file:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method=='GET':
        fileType = request.data
        if fileType=='ode':
            return jsonify({'downloadString':'ODE File Here'})
        if fileType=='mathematica':
            return jsonify({'downloadString':'Mathematica File Here'})
```

However, request.data is the empty string so I've been trying to work around that for quite a while and still haven't found a way. How can I get that piece of data from the request object?

Comment: I think you cannot send data in a get request only in post, you should use a query strings instead

Comment: How would that work? As part of the request's url then use a new @app.route to handle that? I'm trying to keep this as a single page application so that none of the user's session disappears

Comment: I know I've gotten data from GET requests before using request.args.get(), but that was with a form, I was hoping there would be a way to do something similar writing my own post request with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd post my final code here in case anybody came upon this question and was wondering about the answer.

### save.js

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/',
            data: {'selected_index':selected_index},
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                downString = response.downloadString;
            }
        });
```

### app.py

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method=='GET':
        if 'selected_index' in request.args:
            fileType = request.args.get('selected_index')
            if fileType=='ode':
                return jsonify({'downloadString':o.getOdeFile()})
            if request.data=='mathml':
                return jsonify({'downloadString':o.getMathML()})
        return render_template('index.html')
```